# How to mock react stripe functions with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, stripe-payments, react-testing-library

I'm fairly new to mocking and in our codebase we work with Stripe and I need to write a few tests to improve coverage. I want to mock the 'paymentRequest' function, and the 'canMakePayment' method but not sure if my approach is syntactically correct. What is the recommended way of mocking stripe. My approach is below

In my component this is how I am using stripe

```
import { useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const [paymentRequest, setPaymentRequest] = React.useState(null);
const stripe = useStripe();

React.useEffect(() => {
  async function doesWalletExist() {
    try {
      if (stripe) {
        const pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
          country: 'GB',
          currency: 'gbp',
          total: {
            label: 'total',
            amount: 0,
          },
          requestPayerName: true,
        });

        // Check the availability of the Payment Request API.
        const result = await pr.canMakePayment();

        if (result && result.applePay) setPaymentRequest(pr);

        pr.on('paymentmethod', async (event) => {
          handlePaymentMethodReceived(event);
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  doesWalletExist();
}, [stripe]);
```

I would like to test if 'paymentRequest' is being called and mock the return value of 'canMakePayment' so I can test if 'setPaymentRequest' is being called correctly under the right conditions, I am not sure how to do this.

Below is how I'm trying to mock stripe

```
const mockPaymentRequest = jest.fn();

const mockStripe = {
  paymentRequest: mockPaymentRequest,
};

jest.mock('@stripe/react-stripe-js', () => ({
  useStripe: jest.fn(() => mockStripe),
}));

const renderComponent = () => {
  render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

it('should call paymentRequest', () => {
  renderComponent();

  expect(mockPaymentRequest).toHaveBeenCalled(); //results in failure
});
```

Comment: You can probably take a look at how the react-stripe-js library has their mocks set up and just use that as a guide (https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/tree/55178aaef21062d98f1f007502f3490833b65df9/test).